# Pull down menu does not appear using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a `pulldown menu` using bootstrap.
But for some reason the `pulldown menu` does not appear.
Do I not understand the concept or is it a typo?

```
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" title="Homepage">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm active">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</button></a>

<a href="about.php" title="About">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"> About</button></a>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm data-toggle="dropdown">   
   <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> My Dropdown</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="drop1.php">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="droop2.php">Dropdown 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, look at your last button declaration, your are missing à double-quote to end the class attribute

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for your sharp eyes P. Lalonde.:-)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" title="Homepage">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm active">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</button>
        </a>

        <a href="about.php" title="About"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"> About</button></a>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm" data-toggle="dropdown"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> My Dropdown</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="drop1.php">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="droop2.php">Dropdown 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Your code**
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm data-toggle="dropdown">`

You missed `"`.

**Correct**
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default sm" data-toggle="dropdown">`